# advanced filter array angularjs

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I'm trying to perform an advanced search with an angular filter. The idea of the filter is to receive two values (maximum and minimum) in an array and copy all intervals that are within the maximum and minimum of another array.

example:
array = {20,32,10, 60, 75, 43, 95}

minimum: 50
maximum: 100

resultant vector = {60, 95} 75.

code:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        if (product[i].precio >= $scope.minimo && product[i].precio <= $scope.maximo)
            return this.products[i];
    }
    return null;
};
```

Comment: you mean to create  a custom filter right

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
angular.filter('someFilter', function() {
    var newArray = [];
    return function(products, min, max) {
        for(var i = 0; i < products.length, i++) {
            if (products[i].precio >= min && products[i].precio <= max) {
                newArray.push(products[i]);
            }
        }
        return newArray;
    };
});
```

And use it like: `<... ng-repeat="products | someFilter:min:max" ...>`