# Filter by numerical range, custom filter - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a filter for AngularJS data. I have 2 inputs, minAgeInput and maxAgeInput.

I would like to return all products/objects (with ng-repeat), where the product's minAge and maxAge are within the boundaries set by the input values.

My filter function looks like this:

or link to [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/z5VjyUQbdb3XSLVd0UCa)

```
$scope.ageRange = function (plane) {
var minAgeProduct = parseFloat(product.minAge);
var maxAgeProduct = parseFloat(product.maxAge);
var minAgeInput = parseFloat($scope.minAge);
var maxAgeInput = parseFloat($scope.maxAge);

if(minAgeInput >= minAgeProduct) {
    if(maxAgeInput <= maxAgeProduct) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
};
```

Comment: Seems like someone asked about the same question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30858071/advanced-filter-array-angularjs :)

Comment: @sirrocco, seems like I answered to the same question twice.

Comment: Yeap ... maybe it was a contest in the office - who can ask the question fastest :))

Comment: @sirrocco, Hahaha that was actually really funny :) But unfortunately not the case (I'm working on a solo project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the functional solution to the question:

```
$scope.ageRange = function (plane) {
    var minAgeProduct = parseFloat(plane.minAge);
    var maxAgeProduct = parseFloat(plane.maxAge);
    var minAgeInput = parseFloat($scope.minAge);
    var maxAgeInput = parseFloat($scope.maxAge);

    if (!isNaN(minAgeInput) && maxAgeProduct < minAgeInput)
        return false;

    if (!isNaN(maxAgeInput) && minAgeProduct > maxAgeInput)
        return false;

    return true;
};
```

A working solution can be found here [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/z5VjyUQbdb3XSLVd0UCa)